# Get an alarm when the line colour turns green in PineScript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

as I mentioned in the title, I want to get an alarm when the line turns green. I make the line colour green or red with average. But I couldn't do it as an alarm. Can you help me?

```
ma1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf1, ta.wma(hl2, length))
ma2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf2, ta.wma(hl2, length))
ma3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf3, ta.wma(hl2, length))

getcolor(avg, tf) =>
    prev = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.wma(hl2, length)[1])
    avg >= prev ? color.green : color.red


plot(ma3, title = '3' , color=getcolor(ma3, tf3), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3)
plot(ma2, title = '2' , color=getcolor(ma2, tf2), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3)
plot(ma1, title = '1' , color=getcolor(ma1, tf1), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alert into your function. This will work whenever the condition is true.

```
getcolor(avg, tf) =>
    prev = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.wma(hl2, length)[1])
    col = avg >= prev ? color.green : color.red
    if avg >= prev
        alert('Green', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    col
```

Comment: Thank you, the alarm is coming but there was a problem. When the line is green, it alarms at every new bar. Can you make it alarm only when there is a color change?

Comment: You would need to check if the avg was greater than the prev the bar before as well. So add an and statement and use the historical reference